# RALINK rt2870 usb wifi device connects on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: authentication, wifi

I have some USB/WIFI adapters RYK-WUBR170GNM - Ralink RT2870. All of them work on windows without any problems but only a half of them works on Linux. I used the mainline Linux kernel to test.

On Linux I tried some things like:

1. Change the ralink firmware
2. Changed the linux kernel version
3. Changed the router and its configuration
4. Enabled and disabled the HW encryption

Testing these devices on an i.MX6 platform and on Ubuntu PC show the same error:

```
[45221.953410] wlx000e8e6b31cc: authenticate with a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78
[45221.973827] wlx000e8e6b31cc: send auth to a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78 (try 1/3)
[45222.012883] wlx000e8e6b31cc: send auth to a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78 (try 2/3)
[45222.044765] wlx000e8e6b31cc: send auth to a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78 (try 3/3)
[45222.074657] wlx000e8e6b31cc: authentication with a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78 timed out
[45224.289394] wlx000e8e6b31cc: authenticate with a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78
[45224.309848] wlx000e8e6b31cc: send auth to a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78 (try 1/3)
[45224.338214] wlx000e8e6b31cc: send auth to a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78 (try 2/3)
[45224.367799] wlx000e8e6b31cc: send auth to a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78 (try 3/3)
[45224.419757] wlx000e8e6b31cc: authentication with a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78 timed out
[45234.626019] wlx000e8e6b31cc: authenticate with a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78
[45234.638221] wlx000e8e6b31cc: send auth to a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78 (try 1/3)
[45234.674221] wlx000e8e6b31cc: send auth to a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78 (try 2/3)
[45234.712415] wlx000e8e6b31cc: send auth to a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78 (try 3/3)
[45234.754760] wlx000e8e6b31cc: authentication with a8:4e:3f:c4:c6:78 timed out
```

Does someone have some advice about how can I continue debuging this authentication problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by lowering the txpower of the wifi module using his command:

```
iwconfig wlx000e8e6b31cc txpower 6
```